# Cant start Maven project due to problems with Java_Home Variable Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, bash, maven, debian, java-home

I started my first back-end course and performed all operations according to the tutors manual.
When I tried to initialize the project with ./mvnw spring-boot:run

I got an error:

```
owntoomanymonster@penguin:~/my-first-rest-app$ ./mvnw spring-boot:run
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /owntoomanymonster/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java
```

here is my java-home variable:

```
owntoomanymonster@penguin:~/my-first-rest-app$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/owntoomanymonster/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64
```

here is a snapshot of my jvm directory:

```
owntoomanymonster@penguin:/lib/jvm$ ls
default-java  java-1.11.0-openjdk-arm64  java-11-openjdk-arm64  openjdk-11
```

and here a snapshot of my bashrc:

GNU nano 5.4                                                                                /home/owntoomanymonster/.bashrc

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.config/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

 export JAVA_HOME=/owntoomanymonster/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64
 export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I have no more idea what to do to get this fixed. I hope anybody knows how to set the Java-home correctly?

Kindest David

1. Manually defined the java-home variable.
2. Updated the bashrc config
3. changed from link to real path  link: java-1.11.0-openjdk-arm64 real path   to real path: java-11-openjdk-arm64

Comment: what does `mvn -version` show?

Comment: Hello Feynman, when i try mvn -version i get the same error : 

owntoomanymonster@penguin:~/my-first-rest-app$ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE  

Maven was installed earlier via apt.
When i run apt install maven i receive this info and version:
owntoomanymonster@penguin:~/my-first-rest-app$ sudo apt install maven
...
maven is already the newest version (3.6.3-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. thx in advance

Comment: For some reason JAVA_HOME seems to be correct but maven has `/bin/java` incorrectly added at the end.  Not sure how that happens as to my knowledge Maven should just be using JAVA_HOME